# What is the proper method of structuring PHP classes as Parent Child?

Tags: php, class, parent-child

I have the following PHP Classes

```
  class.property.php 
  class.location.php
  class.amenity.php
  class.category.php
```

all four classes handles the respective CRUD operations for different categories. i want to refactor my codes and hence wants to go with the Parent Child Structure.

for example i used to initialize classes on every page like this.

```
$property = new Property($dbh);
$location = new Location($dbh);
$category = new Category($dbh);
$amenity = new Amenity($dbh);
```

and then i used to access class methods and properties individually like

```
$property->user;
$property->contact;
$property->save();

$location->countries();
$location-states();
```

Andso on, every class is executing indivdually, instead of accessing it like this i would like to use it this way.

```
$property = new Property($dbh)
```

above should be the Parent class and rest three child class, and so i should be able to access all class methods and properties only through parent class for example i should only be able to access it like this..

```
$property->location->countries();
$property->locations->states();
$property->location->countryId;
$property->amenity->name;
$property->amenity->save();
```

and so on..

i tried to figure out how to do it and came out with this solution.

```
class Property{
    public $amenity;
    public function __construct() {
        require_once('class.amenity.php');
        $this->amenity = new Amenity;
    }
}

class Amenity {
    public function create($test) {
        return $test;
    }
}
```

now if i want to access the create() method in Amenity class i simply call

```
$property->amenity->create()
```

and it works, however i would like to know if this is the correct method of implementing the Parent Child Structure or am i missing something?

Comment: is there a reason why you want to stick with this format? or is it because you used a different programming language before?

Comment: Offtopic: it might be worth reading about autoloaders - either `__autoload()` or `spl_autoload_register()`. They allow you to get rid of all those *manual* `require_once`, `include_once` etc for loading classes.

Comment: @lbu i think cakephp uses the same format, do you have any better solution to offer?

Comment: @binaryLV thank you, i am going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the `create()` call:

```
class Property{
    public $amenity;
    public function __construct() {
        require_once('class.amenity.php');
        $this->amenity = new Amenity;
    }
}

class Amenity {
}

$property = new Property;
$amenity = $property->amenity;
```

At the very most, you'll want to make the properties protected, and use getters and setters.

Comment: is there any example demonstrating the example of what you just posted i am getting confused

Comment: I assume so... In the above code, $amenity contains what you seem to be trying to do with $property->amenity->create().